# can't make child form stay on top in MS access

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have a full-screen form (using popup) which contains a button that launches a child form. I read that I have to set the child form as popup to make it stay on top. I've done that, but it is still not working. After more googling around, I found out that it's not working because the parent form is also set to popup. How to solve this problem with maintaining the parent form in full screen mode?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask a picture is worth a thousand words. Why is the parent form a popup? You can max the aplication window http://www.devhut.net/2011/02/15/ms-access-vba-minimizemaximize-access-application/ so you don't need a popup for the parent form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, you need to open child form and it should stay above main form. Both forms should be popup, but if the size of child form will be less than main form, user can click on main form and child form disappears under main one even if child form has Modal property. If you don't want this, just open child form with `acDialog` WindowMode parameter.